index function returning #Value in UDF
Public Function GetK12(X) As Integer
    
    K12_Values = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K12").Range("B4:B6980")
    GetK12 = Application.Index(K12_Values, X)
End Function

Calling this from my worksheet returns a #VALUE error. I have validated the variables. An INSERT-MATCH works on this variable elsewhere. What am I doing wrong here?
[this is a snippet I tested. NOT the complete function]
SOLVED: Thank you all. Yeah I had to fiddle with the variable types.

To debug this, call it from a Sub. You may need to specify the 3rd parameter of Index. Side note: consider using As Variant instead of As Integer, and specifying a type for X, e.g. ByVal X As Long.

Consider using ThisWorkbook instead of ActiveWorkbok.

Is K12_Values a range, if so will need to be Set

In MS365, the use of UDFs is mostly obsolete. In the Name Manager, use e.g. GetK12 as the Name and the formula =LAMBDA(r,INDEX('K12'!B4:B6980,r)) as the Refers to, acquiring the same functionality (keeping the workbook in .xlsx format if necessary).

To debug this, call it from a Sub:
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print GetK12(1)
End Sub

You'll likely get a Type Mismatch error, and your likely fix is multi-part:

Change As Integer to As Variant.
Specify the column number, since Index can return an array.

Other recommendations:

Change ActiveWorkbook to ThisWorkbook.
Specify the type for X.
Declare your variables.
Add Application.Volatile to force recalculation of the UDF, e.g. when a cell in B4:B6980 is changed.

Public Function GetK12(ByVal X As Long) As Variant
    Application.Volatile

    Dim K12_Values As Variant    
    K12_Values = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("K12").Range("B4:B6980").Value
    GetK12 = Application.Index(K12_Values, X, 1)
End Function


I just tested this code. But, this code returns nothing in the immediate window.

Add an Application.Volatile to update the result if the retrieved value is changed.

@VBasic2008 good point ... makes me like this UDF a little less.

Luckily, you have no choice.

Don't you think that using the range would be more appropriate i.e. Dim K12_Values As Range: Set K12_Values = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("K12").Range("B4:B6980") led by the logic that if Application.Match is faster applied on a range than on an array, so is Application.Index? Just something to think about.

I suppose you could test using a Range for speed, but the _Values suggested the use of an array, so I continued with that approach.

This is a range.
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K12").Range("B4:B6980")

Also, do not need "Application" above
Therefore you should set it like
Set K12_Values = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("K12").Range("B4:B6980")

Then call the function.
Example:
Sub TestMacro()
Debug.Print GetK12(2)
End Sub

This code is tested.
